# How to create "hovering" buttons in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I saw a Silverlight effect the other that I quite liked, and I was wondering how to reproduce it. The main screen of the app had 5 or 6 large buttons that were gently moving up and down a few pixels, as if they were hovering.

Could someone provide me with some XAML to achieve this effect?

Comment: Do you have a link to the app so we know exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: It was actually for a WPF app, but I assumed that Silverlight could do the same. It was called "Silicon Studio Software Demo", and you should be able to find it with google (currently on restricted internet access, sorry!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a blank usercontrol and one button called button:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="sbHover" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="-4"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button x:Name="button" Height="79" Margin="177,128,236,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Button" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded +=new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sbHover.Begin();
    }
}
```

You could tweak the easing times and values to change the speed and distance it bobs by, equally you could add an easing to get a nicer bounce effect.